# Appending to the Select part of a query

Tags: c#, sql, linq

We have a duplicate part of our LINQ METHOD syntax query. Here is a contrived example.

```
    IQueryable<orders> query  = _context.Set<orders>();

    var result = query.Select(p => new{
        REMAINING = p.qtyOrdered + p.alreadysent,
        AWATING = p.qtyOrdered + p.alreadysent          
    }).ToList();
```

So we are trying to resolve the duplicate part by putting something in a method and then calling that and getting some sort of result. So something like this....

```
    private IQueryable WhatsLeft()
    {
        IQueryable<orders> query  = _context.Set<orders>();
        return query.Select(p => new{p.qtyOrdered + p.alreadysent});
    }

    IQueryable<orders> query  = _context.Set<orders>();

    var result = query.Select(p => new{
        REMAINING = WhatsLeft(),
        AWATING = WhatsLeft()           
    }).ToList();
```

Is this at all possible and if so can anyone give me some brief advise on how I would achieve this.

Comment: Are you looking for a list of orders, with remaining/awaiting per order, or just a total of those 2 for all your orders?

Comment: probably look into `LINQ Expression`

Comment: Why would you even need both remaining and awaiting properties if they are identical?

Comment: Your code and question are not clear. Which part of code does what? What duplicate part you want to remove?

Comment: Remaining/awating per order. Just really trying to see how we could place the LINQ into a separate method completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't you just simply pass the Order object to the new function directly?

```
private int Total(Order order)
{
  return order.qtyOrdered + order.alreadySent;
}

IQueryable<orders> query  = _context.Set<orders>();

var result = query.Select(p => new{
  REMAINING = Total(p),
  AWATING = Total(p)           
}).ToList();
```

If I understand what you're after correctly. I can't remember off the top of my head how well Linq to sql etc can handle functions, interpreting them into SQL functions. Maybe you could give it a try.

Alternatively, to reduce the complexity of the function (to facilitate L2S conversion) you can make the parameters granular on the function such as:

```
private int Total(int left, int right)
{
  return left + right;
}
```

Then make the call more like:

```
var result = query.Select(p => new{
  REMAINING = Total(p.qtyOrdered, p.alreadysent),
  AWATING = Total(p.qtyOrdered, p.alreadysent)
}).ToList();
```

**UPDATE:**

Have you thought about querying the calculation up front?

```
var result = query.Select(c => c.qtyOrdered + c.alreadysent).Select(p => new {
  REMAINING = p,
  AWAITING = p
}).ToList();
```

Comment: DB cannot take functions, but EF can convert a method call expression tree into relevant sql query at run-time

Comment: I've updated the answer, let me know if that's more what you wanted to achieve.